# Read external files from resources Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing an application with Unity in VR, I need to read a filename, which inserts the user, to be uploaded within the application and other 2-3 options that always the user could choose. I had thought of an initial menu in which to put that data but it is not practical for a VR solution. So I had thought of creating a ' setting ' file where the user, before starting the application, inserts the options, the name and the path of the file from which to load the data. But I do not know how to read a file that is outside the resources of the Unity project. Also how can I create this file setting so that it is always in the same location after I Build the project and is visible within the EXE folder? Would anyone know how to help me? Or maybe give me some advice on how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the stack!

I suppose you are creating a desktop-based game? For your case I suggest using the [StreamingAsset folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) to store the config file. When you build the game it will be placed in `<BuildFolder>/<GameName>_Data/StreamingAssets`.

For loading a file, you can use any of C#'s many different `System.IO` classes, a simple way to read file's content as text could be something like this:

```cs
      var path = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/settings.txt";
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
      {
        try
        {
          var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
          /* do something with the content here */
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
          Debug.Log(e);
        }
      }
```

Another approach for your situation, which I think is more user-friendly, is to use something like [FileBrowser](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/file-browser-standalone-98716) asset which allow user to choose a file in a keyboard-free manner. I don't know if it works with VR though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. The first solution should work perfectly since the user will be going to be reading that file which is then read by the system.

Comment: Glad to see it helps. If you confirmed the solution to work, please accept my answer to help later users :)

Comment: Sure, as soon as I have tested I will leave the feedback:-)

Comment: You should prefer the `persistentDataPath` for storing e.g. setting `This value is a directory path where you can store data that you want to be kept between runs. When you publish on iOS and Android, persistentDataPath points to a public directory on the device. Files in this location are not erased by app updates.` since the `streamingAssets` are often read-only and on some platforms (webgl, Android) not even 100% supported. `It is not possible to access the StreamingAssets folder on WebGL and Android platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. `

Comment: Sure but persistentDataPath is not inside the build folder as the op need, and on desktop build it’s in pretty weird places.